# undefined method `downcase!' for 0:Fixnum in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have the following error when submitting my registration information:

```
   NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create

undefined method `downcase!' for 0:Fixnum
```

\livu_pamatskola\app\views\devise\registrations\new.html.erb:

```
<h1>Reģistrācija</h1>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

<div id="contacts">
    <div id="title"><%= f.label "Vārds" %></div>
    <div id="information"><%= f.text_field :name %></div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div id="title"><%= f.label "Uzvārds" %></div>
    <div id="information"><%= f.text_field :surname %></div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div id="title"><%= f.label "E-pasts" %></div>
    <div id="information"><%= f.text_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div id="title"><%= f.label "Parole" %></div>
    <div id="information"><%= f.password_field :password %></div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div id="title"><%= f.label "Vēlreiz parole" %></div>
    <div id="information"><%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>
</div>
    <div><%= f.submit "Reģistrēties", :id => "button-link" %></div>
<% end %>
```

I understand that the problem is in Registrations Controller, as I think, but I don't have a such controller. I have searched all over the internet for solutions, but I haven't find anything, just spent a lot of time, so I need your help.

Trace:

```
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb:36:in `try'
devise (2.2.1) lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb:172:in `apply_to_attribute_or_variable'
devise (2.2.1) lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb:163:in `block in downcase_keys'
devise (2.2.1) lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb:163:in `each'
devise (2.2.1) lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb:163:in `downcase_keys'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:407:in `_run__271922054__validation__371060191__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_validation_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
activemodel (3.2.8) lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:53:in `run_validations!'
activemodel (3.2.8) lib/active_model/validations.rb:194:in `valid?'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/validations.rb:69:in `valid?'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/validations.rb:77:in `perform_validations'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/validations.rb:50:in `save'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:241:in `block (2 levels) in save'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:295:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:293:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:241:in `block in save'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:252:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:240:in `save'
devise (2.2.1) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:15:in `create'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:436:in `_run__1051681660__process_action__714589613__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:42:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:339:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:473:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__646451992__call__371060191__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

**Problem solved:**

When I was creating my user model for Devise, I included email attribute in migration. Problem was there when adding devise to user model, it adds email fields by default too, so it was conflicting with my previous migration.

I am glad that I have solved it, because I don't have a time for these bugs. Thank you all for helping.

Comment: It is not your controller but the controller that is in the Devise Gem: [Registrations_Controller](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb)

Comment: Thank you for correcting me, but where I can find and edit this controller?

Comment: I would not suggest editing the Devise controllers unless you have a real good reason and know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: But how to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your user model has wrong type of attributes. Make sure your database contains valid type of fields. Learn more here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Your problem might be related to known case-insensitive keys issue. Add folowing snippet to your config/initializers/devise.rb file: http://anti-pattern.com/case-insensitive-keys-with-devise

Registration controller is defined in Devise library and it is automatically added to your application controllers if you add devise to the Gemfile.

Comment: You can't edit this controller. It is part of Devise library. The only way to edit this is to fork Devise project on github, edit it and deliver library as your own gem. I suggest you to fix your user model and you will get rid of this error.

Comment: Your problem might be related to known case-insensitive keys issue. Add folowing snippet to your config/initializers/devise.rb file: http://anti-pattern.com/case-insensitive-keys-with-devise

Comment: @Konrad Technically, you could edit the controller by creating a new controller that inherits from `Devise::RegistrationsController` and then just override whichever method you'd like. You'd then have to add some lines to `routes.rb` to point to the controller using means explained in the Devise readme.

Comment: This snippet was in config/initializers/devise.rb by default.

Comment: I will accept your answer, because you showed me the right way - there was a problem in database. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you submitting numerical information for some of the fields? Like, "123" for the username? That could be an issue with Devise if it is getting a number as a string, but thinking it's actually a number.

Comment: `"123".downcase #=> "123"`

Comment: a = 123; a.downcase!  
NoMethodError: undefined method `downcase!' for 123:Fixnum

Comment: Any information coming through `params` would be a string. Devise would then have to explicitly convert the parameter to a `Fixnum` before calling `.downcase!` on it in order to get this error for the reason you are suggesting.